# Passing values from one fragment to another

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, retrofit

I'm working in Kotlin and using retrofit. I have a recycler view, which consists of cards. Each card has a typeName and an image associated to it which for now I have added statically using dataclass. Now, I need to pass the typeName only from the CategoryFragment to the LocationFragment once the user clicks on a particular card. And at the LocationFragment I want to check the latitude, longitude and typeName from the database if it already exists.

**Here's my code for the dataclass of Category:**
data class Category_dataclass ( val category_image : Int , val typeName: String)

**Here's my code for the CategoryFragment:**

```
package com.example.atry.MakeComplaint

import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.atry.History.Complaints
import com.example.atry.History.MyComplainRecyclerViewAdapter

import com.example.atry.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.existing_complaint_popup.*


class CategoryFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false)
        val recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.category_list) as RecyclerView

        recyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context!!, 2)
        }

        //creating an arraylist to store category using the data class user
        val category = ArrayList<Category_dataclass>()

        //adding some dummy data to the list of categories
        category.add(Category_dataclass((R.drawable.trash) , "Water"))
        category.add(Category_dataclass((R.drawable.fire) , "Sewerage"))
        category.add(Category_dataclass((R.drawable.dustbin) , "load"))




        //creating our adapter
        val adapter = CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter(category)

        //now adding the adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v



    }




    }
```

**Here's the CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter:**

```
package com.example.atry.MakeComplaint

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.atry.History.ComplaintDetailsFragment
import com.example.atry.History.Complaints
import com.example.atry.MakeComplaint.Category_dataclass
import com.example.atry.MakeComplaint.CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter
import com.example.atry.R
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter(val categoryList: ArrayList<Category_dataclass>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {




    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_category_single, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    //this method is binding the data on the list
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(categoryList[position])
        holder.mView.setOnClickListener{view->



            val lFragment = LocationFragment()
            val oldFragment = CategoryFragment()
            val manager = (holder.mView.context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
            val transaction =  manager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(
                R.id.first_screen_of_makecomplaint,
                lFragment
            ) // give your fragment container id in first parameter
            transaction.show(lFragment)
            transaction.hide(oldFragment)
            transaction.isAddToBackStackAllowed
            transaction.addToBackStack(oldFragment.fragmentManager.toString())  // if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
            transaction.commit()

        }
    }


    //this method is giving the size of the list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return categoryList.size
    }


    inner class ViewHolder(val mView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mView) {
        fun bindItems(cat:Category_dataclass) {
            val imageViewName = mView.findViewById(R.id.category_image) as ImageView
            val textViewtext = mView.findViewById(R.id.category_text) as TextView

            imageViewName.setImageResource(cat.category_image)
            textViewtext.text = cat.typeName


        }



    }

}
```

**And this is my retrofit:**

```
 //to check existing complaint

    @GET("api/existingComplain")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    fun checkExistingComplain(@Query("typeName") typeName:String,
                              @Query("longitude") longitude:String,
                              @Query("latitude") latitude:String):Observable<Observables.checkExistingResult>
```

**I've created and object where i stored the dataclass which will return the following:**

```
data class checkExistingResult(val description:String , val Complain:String)
```

if the typeName and location already exists in the database I want the description and Complain to be displayed on a material styled dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**1st Step:-**

```
val dashboard = "Dashboard"
```

take variable like this you can take it's name as your fragment name so page name you can check like this `MainActivity().dashboard`

Now, **2nd Step:-**

create one class and write function like this in that class

```
 fun openPage(
    activity: Activity,
    pagename: String?, model: PaymentDetails
) {
    when (pagename) {

            MainActivity().dashboard -> {
                val mfragment = DashboardFragment()
                (activity as MainActivity).fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.nav_host, mfragment).commit()

                val a = Bundle()
                a.putSerializable("model", model)
                mfragment.arguments = a
            }
        }
    }
```

take key value pair as I take my whole model and key is **model** in my code you can write any thing.

**3rd Step:-**

Make your model **Serializable**

**4th Step:-** When you are adding your values into model add details and add your model for method in which you want to use these values like following

```
val payment = PaymentDetails(
            type,
            price,
            name,
            id,
         )
        paymentData!!.add(payment)
        CustomMethods().openPagePaymentDetails(
            activity!!,
            MainActivity().sessionPaymentFragment, payment
        )
```

**5th Step:-**

Declare and initialise your object with type of your model like following:

```
 //Declare 
 private var model: PaymentDetails? = null 

//initialise
 model = arguments!!.getSerializable("model") as PaymentDetails?
```

And now finally you can access value of previous fragment into your next fragment like this,

```
var type: String
type = model!!.type
```

**Note:- please do no forgot to make your model class Serializable**

Hope so it will help you.